# How to design spark program to process 300 most recent files?

Tags: apache-spark

## Situation

New small files comes in periodically. I need to do calculation on recent 300 files. So basically there is a window moving forward. The size of the window is 300 and I need do calculation on the window.

But something very important to know is that this is not a spark stream computing. Because in spark stream, the unit/scope of window is time. Here the unit/scope is number of files.

## Solution1

I will maintain a dict, the size of the dict is 300. Each new file comes in, I turn it into spark data frame and put it into dict. Then I make sure the oldest file in the dict is popped out **if the length of dict is over 300**. 
After this I will merge all data frames in the dict to a bigger one and do calculation.

The above process will be run in a loop. Every time new file comes in we go through the loop.

## pseudo code for solution 1

```
for file in file_list:
    data_frame = get_data_frame(file)
    my_dict[ timestamp ] = data_frame

    for timestamp in my_dict.keys():
        if timestamp older than 24 hours:
            # not only unpersist, but also delete to make sure the memory is released 
            my_dict[timestamp].unpersist
            del my_dict[ timestamp ] 

    # pop one data frame from the dict
    big_data_frame = my_dict.popitem()

    for timestamp in my_dict.keys():
        df = my_dict.get( timestamp )
        big_data_frame = big_data_frame.unionAll(df)

    # Then we run SQL on the big_data_frame to get report
```

## problem for solution 1

Always hit **Out of memory** or **gc overhead limit**

## question

Do you see anything inappropriate in the solution 1?

Is there any better solution?

Is this the right kind of situation to use spark ?

Comment: You said your window of computation is 300 right? But in solution 1 if you pop out the oldest file, then you still have 299 older files right? Can you please clarify my understanding?

Comment: @LokeshKumarP Hi, I modified the question.  I will check the dict before I pop out data. If the total length of dict is not reach 300, then I do not pop anything. Tell me if still not clear

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, what is the size of each file, and also you mentioned it is not streaming job, so how frequently do you poll the file system?

Comment: @LokeshKumarP I added some pseudo code. size of file is 4KB. The cluster is spark stand alone cluster. As per the frequency. Once a loop is over, I will do the next loop as long as there are still files in the directory.

Comment: When you have the big dataFrame how many partitions does it have? Single or multiple, and also what query are you running because the memory usage also depends on what SQL constructs you use right ?

Comment: What I generally would do, is to loop over after a certain amount of pause, coz if the file frequency is less you will have to loop more frequently which is again a burden on cpu

Comment: The frequency may be a issue. But the memory should not because each file is only 4KB so even 300 files is only 1200KB = 1.2M.  And I assign a few G memory to both the worker and master. I did not control the partition.

Comment: The SQL I use is dataframe.show(). I did not run any real sql yet because I want to make sure the system can run..

Answer (score 0):

One observation, you probably don't want to use `popitem`, the keys of a Python dictionary are not sorted, so you can't guarantee that you're popping the earliest item. Instead I would recreate the dictionary each time using a sorted list of timestamps. Assuming your filenames are just timestamps:

```
my_dict = {file:get_dataframe(file) for file in sorted(file_list)[-300:]}
```

Not sure if this will fix your problem, can you paste the full stacktrace of your error into the question? It's possible that your problem is happening in the Spark merge/join (not included in your question).

Comment: Thanks maxymoo. I actually using timestamp as the key of dict. So it will not be a problem to find the oldest data frame. The stack trace is too much.. But you are right I will post it out later. Thanks

Comment: no my point is that if you are going to use `pop` to remove the oldest item, you would need to use an `OrderedDict` -- an ordinary dict doesn't always sort the keys, so you can't guarantee `pop` will get the earliest date.

Comment: thanks. I am actually not really using the simple pop method. I use normal dict. Then use the key to judge if the corresponding item should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to this is streaming, but not with respect to time, I mean you will still have some window and sliding interval set, but say it is 60 secs.

So every 60 secs you get the DStream of file contents, in 'x' partitions. These 'x' partitions represent the files you drop onto HDFS or file system.
So, this way you can keep track of how many files/partitions have been read, if they are less than 300 then wait until they become 300. After the count hits 300 then you can start processing.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to keep track of the most recent files or if it's possible to just discover them once in a while, then I'd suggest to do something like

```
sc.textFile(','.join(files));
```

or if it's possible to identify specific pattern to get those 300 files, then

```
sc.textFile("*pattern*");
```

And it's even possible to have comma separated patterns, but it might happen that some files that match more, than one pattern, would be read more, than once.

Comment: Hi thanks. Yes we can use the pattern way. But the problem is just like what you said, some files may be read more than once. That is why I use a dict to track those files which are already read. I want to avoid those read cost

Comment: Then join them into comma separated list and read every time. The code is that much simple, so I wouldn't worry too much about disk reads performance. There are SSDs, there are disks buffers. And what is percentage of time to read vs time to process. Anyway, I'd measure time to read if that's a concern, but most probably just end up with simpler code =)